# How to handle binary post data in Express?

Tags: node.js, image, express

I am wanting to post an image in the form of binary to my Express app.

I'm assuming it should come through in the `req.body` object but will need some form of middleware to be able to handle binary data?

When I send an image as binary from postman and try log req.body, the object is empty.

I am using express-generator as a boilder plate which comes with `body-parser` like so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

I had a look at Multer but think that is just for multipart data

Also looked at busboy but couldn't figure out if that will handle binary data.

Am I correct that the post data will still come through in req.body?
And what middleware do I need to handle binary data?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method I ended up using:

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next) {

  const image = req.file.buffer

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't use the body-parser to handle the binary data like files and stuff like that. But wut you can do is use a module call `formidable` to handle this

Example snipper

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, (error, fields, files) => {
    if(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
    
    console.log(fields.name)
    
    const cuteCat = files.cat_image;
    
    console.log(cuteCat.name) // The origin file name
    console.log(cuteCat.path) // The temporary file name something like /tmp/<random string>
    
  })
});
```

```html
<input name="cat_image" type="file" />
<input name="name" type="text" />
```

Comment: So does that mean I have to remove body-parser completely? Meaning other endpoints will need to have a custom method of parsing the response to json?

Comment: You don't have to remove body-parse completely, cuz body-parse is good for parsing raw JSON and raw form data